# Calling Job B from a Job A and don't wait for B to complete but continue with execution of Job A - Groovy Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following situation:

```
Job A {
  some methods being called ...
  ..
  ..
  build(
     job: 'Job B',
     parameters: [
        string(
           name: 'XYZ',
           value: 'abc',
        )
     ]
  )
  
  some more methods to execute ...
  ...
  ...

}
```

Now in the above situation I have to wait for Job B to finish and then it continues further with steps in Job A. Is there a way to trigger Job B and still continue with execution of Job A without waiting for B to complete?

Comment: Specify `build(..., wait: false)`

Comment: Wow, that was easy, and it did work for me. Thank you so much for your help and also the response time.

Answer (score 3):

Following would do the trick

```
build(
   job: 'Job B',
   parameters: [
     string(
       name: 'XYZ',
       value: 'abc',
     )
   ],
   wait: false
)
```

From build step documentation https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)

> wait (optional)
> If true, the pipeline will wait for the result of the build step before jumping to > the next step. Defaults to true.
> Type: boolean

Comment: Wow, that was easy, and it did work for me. Thank you so much for your help and also the response time.

Comment: But how can I know the build id of the triggered job?